# How to Remove the underline from Sqlplus output

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

There is **Bash script** which i use to export some data from Oracle dataBase and Insert it Into Text File.

The problem is when i export the Data to Text file , there is always some line in output file which i need to remove it.

Need to remove ------ in Output.

There is Bash script putting below Parameter

```
sqlplus -s ${DB_CONNECTION} << EOF > temp.$$
set colsep ','
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 256
set trimspool on
set feedback off
set trim on
spool

--Query

spool off
```

Output will be :

```
SDATE     ,ERROR_CODE                  ,STATUS      ,PROCESS                       ,FAILURE_COUNT
----------,----------------------------------------,--------------------,--------------------------------------------------,----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SET UNDERLINE OFF

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 30 08:11:28 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Wed May 30 2018 08:05:09 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

```
SQL> set underline off
SQL> set pagesize 10
SQL> set linesize 80
SQL> col first_name format a20
SQL> col last_name format a20
SQL> select first_name, last_name from hr.employees fetch first 6 rows only;

FIRST_NAME       LAST_NAME
Ellen            Abel
Sundar           Ande
Mozhe            Atkinson
David            Austin
Hermann          Baer
Shelli           Baida

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

From the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm)

SET UND[ERLINE] {- | c | ON | OFF}
Sets the character used to underline column headings in reports. The underline character cannot be an alphanumeric character or a white space. ON or OFF turns underlining on or off. ON changes the value of c back to the default "-".

SET UNDERLINE is only supported in iSQL*Plus when preformatted output is On (SET MARKUP HTML PREFORMAT).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to suppress the complete heading, use

```
set heading off
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG082

If you want to see the column names, but not the line below, use:

```
set underline off
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG159

Answer (score 0):

My previous  Solution was

```
sed -i '/-/d' temp
```

But the best is to put

```
underline off
```